# How to divide a large text into multiple chunks, all with the same max-height?

Tags: html, css

CSS3's column-module allows you to divide your text into a multiple columns. Either by

1) specifying the column-height property (all columns will have the same author-defined height, the column count is dynamic)

or,

2) specifying the column-count property (all columns have the same computer-generated height, the number of columns is defined by the author).

What I would like to have is option 1, but instead of having the columns next to each-other I'd like to have them underneath each other. This way they wouldn't really be *columns*, but more like *rows* with a defined height.

This way the text will be divided into pages of all the same height. (Like when you print out a webpage.)

Any ideas on how to achieve this? ( My project only requires webkit-support. )

Comment: Couldn't you achieve much the same by just using paragraphs and specifying a `height`?

Comment: Well sometimes the 'text' exists out of multiple paragraphs, sometimes it includes images, lists, etc. It's very dynamic and I can't force it to fit into a specific height. That's why the multi-column think works great: it automatically wraps the content to fit. – Only thing is, I want rows instead of columns.

Answer (score 0):

The column module won't do that. You would be better off declaring a class on a div with the a declared height. If you're looking for dynamic columns, you may need to do some programming via js or php.

Comment: I guess using Javascript might be a solution. I can probably calculate where to chop off the text and put each chunk in a separate DIV. – Any ideas on where to start?

Comment: That way lies insanity. Basically you're trying to create CSS3 paged media queries with an extension for column handling. Paged media queries aren't supported even in edge browsers yet.

Answer (score 0):

By the way, I *did* play with the following idea which sort of works:

1. Use a multi-column DIV to split the text into different same-height chunks.
2. Copy the multi-column DIV X times, where X = number of generated columns.
3. On each DIV, only show one column. (by using overflow: hidden and a width)
4. Position the columns so they are underneath each-other.

This works, but is VERY slow as you can imagine.

Perhaps there's a way to show the same multi-column DIV multiple times with different view-ports, without copying the whole DOM tree?

Answer (score 0):

JS seems like the way to go. Check out this [jQuery function from the Filament Group](http://filamentgroup.com/lab/setting_equal_heights_with_jquery/). [Masonry](http://desandro.com/resources/jquery-masonry/) might be of interest too.

```
// make columns equal height
function equalHeight(group) {
  tallest = 0;
  group.each(function() {
    thisHeight = $(this).height();
    if(thisHeight > tallest) {
      tallest = thisHeight;
    }
  });
  group.height(tallest);
}
```